# Round corners of a listView get edgy when selected in android

Tags: android, listview, layout, background, rounded-corners

I have a list view which items use a rounded-corner image for a background. The thing is that when the user selects an item, the whole area (the rounded-corner image plus the small gaps which would complete the item to a rectangle) gets selected. How do I deal with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user selects an item Android displays the drawable specified by android:selectorDrawable, which is by default rectangular.

You'll have to replace this with your own selector drawable which has rounded corners.

Comment: where exactly should I do this?